# Table bubble plot with pandas and altair

Tags: python, pandas, altair

I have the following `df_teams_full_stats`:

```
Data columns (total 35 columns):
 #   Column                 Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                 --------------  -----  
 0   Unnamed: 0             428 non-null    int64  
 1   MatchID                428 non-null    int64  
 2   For Team               428 non-null    object 
 3   Against Team           428 non-null    object 
 4   Date                   428 non-null    object 
 5   GameWeek               428 non-null    int64  
 6   Home                   428 non-null    object 
 7   Possession             428 non-null    float64
 8   Touches                428 non-null    int64  
 9   Passes                 428 non-null    int64  
 10  Tackles                428 non-null    int64  
 11  Clearances             428 non-null    int64  
 12  Corners                428 non-null    int64  
 13  Offsides               428 non-null    int64  
 14  Fouls Committed        428 non-null    int64  
 15  Yellow Cards           428 non-null    int64  
 16  Goals                  428 non-null    int64  
 17  XG                     428 non-null    float64
 18  Shots On Target        428 non-null    int64  
 19  Total Shots            428 non-null    int64  
 20  Goals Conceded         428 non-null    int64  
 21  Shots Conceded         428 non-null    int64  
 22  XGC                    428 non-null    float64
 23  Shots In Box           428 non-null    int64  
 24  Close Shots            428 non-null    int64  
 25  Headers                428 non-null    int64  
 26  Shots Centre           428 non-null    int64  
 27  Shots Left             428 non-null    int64  
 28  Shots Right            428 non-null    int64  
 29  Shots In Box Conceded  428 non-null    int64  
 30  Close Shots Conceded   428 non-null    int64  
 31  Headers Conceded       428 non-null    int64  
 32  Shots Centre Conceded  428 non-null    int64  
 33  Shots Left Conceded    428 non-null    int64  
 34  Shots Right Conceded   428 non-null    int64  
dtypes: float64(3), int64(28), object(4)
memory usage: 117.2+ KB
```

Which I'm trying to group and sort in order to achieve this chart:

[image]

Following this example: [table_bubble_plot_github](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/table_bubble_plot_github.html), the idea is to have some target 'x', say 'Goals', that will determine the bubble size of all teams playing against all others.

This is what I have so far:

```
def team_match_ups(df_teams_full_stats, x, y):
    target_x = x[0]
    target_y = y[0]

    df_temp =  df_teams_full_stats.set_index("For Team")
    df_temp.fillna(0.0, inplace=True)

    df_temp[target_x] = df_temp.groupby(['For Team'])[target_x].mean()
    X = df_temp[target_x].to_frame()
    print ("x", X)

    df_temp[target_y] = df_temp.groupby(['For Team'])[target_y].mean()
    Y = df_temp[target_y].to_frame()

    df = df_temp.reset_index()

    #sorted_teams = sorted(df_teams_full_stats['For Team'].unique())

    bubble_plot = alt.Chart(df).mark_circle().encode(
            alt.Y(f'{target_x}:O', bin=True),
            alt.X(f'{target_y}:O', bin=True),
            alt.Size(f'{target_x}:Q',
            scale=alt.Scale(range=[0, 1500])),
            #alt.Color('Color', legend=None, scale=None),
            tooltip = [alt.Tooltip(f'{target_x}:Q'),
                       alt.Tooltip(f'{target_y}:Q')],
        )


return bubble_plot
```

But this is far from ideal:

[image]

---

**QUESTION**

How can I have teams names naming x and y grids and target_x setting the bubble size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the x and y axis to be team names, you should map the x and y encodings to the columns containing team names. It might look something like this (untested because you did not provide access to your data):

```
alt.Chart(df_teams_full_stats).mark_circle().encode(
  x='For Team:N',
  y='Against Team:N',
  size='Goals:Q'
)
```

Comment: this works. two comments: 1) how can I assign 'color' to a given target? 2) how do I write annotation for x axis on top of the chart, i order to make it simetric? I mean how do I put team names of x axis on top?

Comment: To assign a color, use a `color` encoding mapped to the column you want to be represented by color. To orient the axis at the top, use `x=alt.X('For Team:N', axis=alt.Axis(orient='top'))`